# RewriteRule on blind link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect a module to another and i tried this on my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /modules\.php\?name=Downloads
RewriteRule ^/modules\.php?name=Downloads$  http://www.b2kill.com/modules.php?name=File_Repository [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /modules\.php\?name=Download_Repository
RewriteRule ^/modules\.php?name=Download_Repository$  http://www.b2kill.com/modules.php?name=File_Repository [L,R=301]
```

obviously is not working because I'm here asking it to you :)

Comment: `obviously is not working` -- What happens? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` directive does not receive the entire URI. Update the rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /modules\.php\?name=Download(?:s|_Repository)
RewriteRule ^/?modules\.php$  http://www.b2kill.com/modules.php?name=File_Repository [L,R=301]
```

The single ruleset above will take care of both your conditions, because of the pattern: `Download(?:s|_Repository)`